# Draw PDFPage without current context

Tags: objective-c, pdf, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

Starting from Sierra the's a pdf `drawWithBox:toContext:` operation available. But in former OS versions this is not present. When there's a graphic context the predecessor `drawWithBox:` worked nicely where ever a context is present (e.g. in `drawRect:`). But if you don't have such a context, I don't see a way to use `drawWithBox:` (except for taking a random context which "might" be present). I tried this:

```
_contextRef =
  CGBitmapContextCreate(_cvMat.data, ... 

...

if (v12) {
  [page drawWithBox:kPDFDisplayBoxBleedBox toContext:cgContext];
} else {
  [NSGraphicsContext  setCurrentContext:(__bridge NSGraphicsContext * _Nullable)(cgContext)];
  [page drawWithBox:kPDFDisplayBoxBleedBox];
}
```

but that just dumped

> -[__NSCFType graphicsPort]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8de1e219a0

which is not an error message encountered (or sought after) very often.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac OS X: Drawing into an offscreen NSGraphicsContext using CGContextRef C functions has no effect. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627557/mac-os-x-drawing-into-an-offscreen-nsgraphicscontext-using-cgcontextref-c-funct) - Definitely this is a duplicate :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that `CGContextRef` and `NSGraphicsContext` are not the same thing. You're calling `+[NSGraphicsContext setCurrent:]` with a `CGContextRef` when its expecting an `NSGraphicsContext` instance.

The good news is that you can create a `NSGraphicsContext` from a `CGContext` quite easily:

```
CGContextRef cgContext;
NSGraphicsContext *newContext = [[NSGraphicsContext alloc] initWithCGContext:cgContext flipped:NO];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrent: newContext];
```

See if that lets you draw your PDF where you expect.

Comment: Where did you get that initializer from? My NSGraphicsContext.h does not have any CGContext-related method and thus the compiler croaks: _No visible @interface for 'NSGraphicsContext' declares the selector 'initWithCGContext:flipped:'_

Comment: Anyhow, you lead me in the right direction and I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627557/mac-os-x-drawing-into-an-offscreen-nsgraphicscontext-using-cgcontextref-c-funct which solved my issue.